# How to Include all 3 sizes of Tile in windows phone 7 app

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I am developing a windows phone.Small and medium are already included.  I want to add the wide size tile into that. How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can include large tile in wp7.8 like this:

```
   public class CheckOSVersion
    {

        private static Version TargetedVersion;

        public static bool IsTargetedVersion
        {
            get { return Environment.OSVersion.Version >= CheckOSVersion.TargetedVersion; }
        }

        static CheckOSVersion() { CheckOSVersion.TargetedVersion = new Version(7, 10, 8858); }

        private static void SetProperty(object instance, string name, object value)
        {
            MethodInfo setMethod = instance.GetType().GetProperty(name).GetSetMethod();
            object[] objArray = new object[1];
            objArray[0] = value;
            setMethod.Invoke(instance, objArray);
        }

        public static void UpdateFlipTile(string title, string backTitle, string backContent, string wideBackContent, int count, Uri tileId, Uri smallBackgroundImage, Uri backgroundImage, Uri backBackgroundImage, Uri wideBackgroundImage, Uri wideBackBackgroundImage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (CheckOSVersion.IsTargetedVersion)
                {
                    Type type = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData, Microsoft.Phone");
                    Type type1 = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone");
                    foreach (ShellTile activeTile in ShellTile.ActiveTiles)
                    {
                        if (activeTile.NavigationUri.ToString() != tileId.ToString() && !activeTile.NavigationUri.ToString().Equals("/Login.xaml?flag=0"))
                        {
                            continue;
                        }
                        object obj = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "Title", title);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "Count", count);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackTitle", backTitle);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackContent", backContent);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "SmallBackgroundImage", smallBackgroundImage);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackgroundImage", backgroundImage);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackBackgroundImage", backBackgroundImage);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "WideBackgroundImage", wideBackgroundImage);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "WideBackBackgroundImage", wideBackBackgroundImage);
                        CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "WideBackContent", wideBackContent);

                        object[] objArray = new object[1];
                        objArray[0] = obj;
                        type1.GetMethod("Update").Invoke(activeTile, objArray);
                        //break;
                    }
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }

        public static void CreateFlipTile(string title, string backTitle, string backContent, string wideBackContent, int count, Uri tileId, Uri smallBackgroundImage, Uri backgroundImage, Uri backBackgroundImage, Uri wideBackgroundImage, Uri wideBackBackgroundImage)
        {
            try
            {
                if (CheckOSVersion.IsTargetedVersion)
                {
                    Type type = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.FlipTileData, Microsoft.Phone");
                    Type type1 = Type.GetType("Microsoft.Phone.Shell.ShellTile, Microsoft.Phone");
                    object obj = type.GetConstructor(new Type[0]).Invoke(null);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "Title", title);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "Count", count);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackTitle", backTitle);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackContent", backContent);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "SmallBackgroundImage", smallBackgroundImage);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackgroundImage", backgroundImage);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "BackBackgroundImage", backBackgroundImage);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "WideBackgroundImage", wideBackgroundImage);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "WideBackBackgroundImage", wideBackBackgroundImage);
                    CheckOSVersion.SetProperty(obj, "WideBackContent", wideBackContent);


                    object[] objArray = new object[1];
                    objArray[0] = obj;
                    MethodInfo createmethod = type1.GetMethod("Create", new[] { typeof(Uri), typeof(ShellTileData), typeof(bool) });
                    createmethod.Invoke(null, new object[] { tileId, obj, true });
                }
            }
            catch { }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The key difference between Windows Phone OS 7.1 and Windows Phone 8
>   Tiles is that Windows Phone OS 7.1 offers only one Tile template. This
>   template is called TileTemplate5, and maps to the flip template in
>   Windows Phone 8.TileTemplate5 is only available in one size, which
>   maps to the medium size in Windows Phone 8.

Please check this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj553779%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) for more information

And i think you are going to add Wide tile in Windows Phone 8 application.Do the following ..
1.Open the `WMManifest.xml` file 
2.Tick `Support for Large Tiles` 
3.Choose the correct image for the `Large[Wide] Tile.`